# Creating data types containing lists and defining functions on them

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

Informally speaking, I made a data type Tdict where each instance of it is  a list of pairs, and each pair consists of a String and a List of Strings; in other languages, I would use a Hash, mapping Strings to Lists of Strings. Since I am learning Haskell, I would like to roll out this structure from scratch, instead of using the Hash package from Haskell.

This is my data type definition of Tdict, using two auxiliary type definitions:

```
-- Pair of two strings
data TPair = TPair String String deriving (Show)

-- Associating one String to a list of Strings
data Tassoc = Tassoc String [String] deriving (Show)

-- type synonym for list of associations
type Tdict = [Tassoc]
```

So far, this is accepted by Haskell, so at least it is syntactically correct. Now I want to define a function, which takes as parameter two strings and a Tdict and returns a Tdict. However, Haskell already rejects the signature definition of the function:

```
insertTdict :: (String k, String v, Tdict d) => k -> v -> d -> Tdict
```

The error message is about both parameters `v` and `d and reads:

```
error:
    • Expected kind ‘* -> Constraint’, but ‘Tdict’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the type signature:
        insertTdict :: (String k, String v, Tdict d) =>
                   k -> v -> d -> Tdict
```

(The error messages for parameters `v` and `d` are identical).

What did I do wrong? I have the feeling, that I am missing something fundamental in Haskell.

I used [this page](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses) as  a reference for defining my data types.

Comment: The `String k, String v`, etc. type constraints do not make any sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your types are *not* typeclasses. A type constraint like `(String k, String v, Tdict d) =>` thus does not make sense.

You can implement the function with:

```
insertTdict :: String -> String -> Tdict -> Tdict
```

Comment: I see. To the left of "=>", I can write something like `Num x`, because `Num` is a type**class**, but `String` is just a type.

Comment: @user1934428 Yes. The rough idea is that a typeclass is "a set/class of types", e.g. `Num` is a class comprising `Int,Integer,Double,Float,...`.